# TI TM4C - Ignoring Float Results

Tags: c

So I'm, among other things, trying to monitor the onboard temperature for a TI TM4C123GH6PM. I'm having some timing issues, and only one of the my two interrupt handlers is being reached, but the real frustrating part right now is that the TM4C is ignoring my Float calculations.

I have the following code:

```
volatile float result;//temp
float temperature;//temp
float numerator;
float fraction;

result = ADC_SSR3;
numerator = ((float)75 * (float)3.3 * result);
fraction = numerator/((float)4096);
temperature = 147.5 - fraction;
```

As a note, the explicit typecasting was a temporary experiment.

I get a legitimate result from SSR3 when I step through but then my locals read as "error" for the following 3 lines. I thought at first that the FPU needed to be enabled (as I've seen in some forums) but I've also read that the compiler in IAR Embedded Workbench does so by default, and I have the "VFPv4 single precision" FPU selected in IAR's General Options for the project.

This is a list of the assembly instructions generated:
[disassembly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdjkG.jpg)

When I step through, I can see the results on the R# registers but I cannot find the S# registers in the register menu (the datasheet calls S0-S15 error registers but I've seen them called single point registers on the web). At the end of each instruction, the results for numerator/fraction/temperature are always still "error".

Anything obvious I typed wrong, or didn't include/call?

Thanks!

Comment: First thing to fix is the `double`-precision literals. Use the `f`-suffix to create `float`-precision literals.

Comment: You mean like "numerator = (75f * 3.3f * result);" ? I tried it, I get a compilation result (expected a ")"), not sure why.

Comment: `volatile` is unnecessary here. Please read what it implies and when to use it. Also don't use floating point on MCUs if avoidable. Your ADC provides an integer result which can be processed using integer arithmetic (possibly emulating fixed-point). Although the MCU has a FPU, integer will be easier and typically faster.

Comment: The problem with using int's is that I lose a ton of precision and my result is way off. For example, I used int's and got a temperature = 30 for one SSR3 output, when I calculated by hand the float result would have been ~23.5. In degrees Celsius, that's a huge difference.

Comment: @PoGaMi Only a floating-point constant can have a `f`-suffix. `75` is an *integer* constant. You could use `75.f` instead.

Comment: @EOF Yup, good call, fixed that part.

Comment: So I did find the issue here: rather than getting rid of the "volatile" keyword on the first variable, I needed to add it to all the variables. This code isn't inside of an ISR, but I do have similar variable inside of an ISR (that I can't reach, different story), so maybe the compiler mapped them as globals for some reason.